# Rename latexmath macro in asciidoc

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

Is there a way I can rename or alias `latexmath` in an AsciiDoc document?

In an ideal world, I'd like to set up an AsciiDoc such that `$...$` is interpreted as LaTeX math, and
`$$...$$` is interpreted as a block equation.  In general, I'm just trying to reduce the number of characters involved in defining a math block since

```
where $c$ is the speed of light and $m_0$ is the rest mass
```

is significantly more readable (to someone who's used LaTeX for years) than

```
where latexmath:[$c$] is the speed of light and latexmath:[$m_0$] is the rest mass
```

The use case I have is that I'm writing technical documentation for upload to a GitLab repository.  I'd like to be able to exploit GitLab's ability to automatically render AsciiDoc format files.  However, these documents are math heavy, so I find the large numbers of `latexmath:[...]` blocks hard to read while editing.

Answer (score 0):

`latexmath` is the name of the macro that handles parsing the LaTeX markup. If you don't specify `latexmath`, `asciidoctor` doesn't know to pass control to an alternate parser.

You could achieve what you're after by writing a pre-processing step that identifies contiguous blocks of LaTeX markup and wraps that markup in `latexmath:[...]`. The updated markup can then be processed by Asciidoctor like normal (assuming that your LaTeX markup identification is accurate). How you go about implementing that is up to you.

Another way, assuming you have some Ruby skills, would be to modify the extension that implements the `latexmath` macro such that it was called, say, `L`. Then your markup would be the more concise:

```
where L:[$c$] is the speed of light and L:[$m_0$] is the rest mass
```